# Hand over FBConnect Session from iPhone >> Backend Server?

Tags: iphone, session, facebook

Good afternoon,

I have a quick 'top level' question regarding the usage of Facebook Connect in an iPhone app which is in fact powered by my own backend. Is it possible that the user does authenticate him/herself with fbconnect on the iphone and the app hands over the session identifier to my server in order to perform whatever I need to do? So basically use FB primarily as authentication & profile storage / retrieval, and everything beyond is actually done / stored by my own backend?

So basically it would look something like this:

iPhone > (authentication) > Facebook

and then

iPhone < (hands over session/token) > My Backend < (uses that token) > Facebook ?

Is that doable?

Cheers and thanks,
-Joerg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, as long as you have the session keys and token you should be able to pick up the session anywhere as long as it doesnt expire.